# How shopify access token scopes are tied on user permissions?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I'm building `Shopify` app in `Nodejs`. And I can not find any resource on how users with different permissions will interact with my app. For example if my app has `read_products` and `write_products` scopes granted but a user has only `read_products` permissions. Will the app be available for him if yes how do I get the user's scopes and more important is there any way to test the scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shopify has explained that in detail in the Authentication section of the documentation. There are two modes for authenticated access, namely Online and Offline.

What you need is Online Access. From [Shopify Docs](https://shopify.dev/concepts/about-apis/authentication#online-access)

> Tokens with online access mode are linked to an individual user on a
> store, where the access token's lifespan matches the lifespan of the
> user's web session. This type of access mode is meant to be used when
> a user is interacting with your app through the web, or when an app
> must respect an individual user's permission level.

Few notable difference as compared to Offline (default) access are

> - This access mode must be explicitly requested in the authorization phase.
> - An API request made using an online mode access token is guaranteed to respect the user's individual permissions. Shopify returns a 403
>   Forbidden status code when the access token is valid but the user does
>   not have access.
> - The app can inspect scope and associated_user_scope to determine if a user is lacking certain permissions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and you are totally right, but I can not get online access token. I use `@shopify/koa-shopify-auth` and set `accessMode` to 'online' as it is described in their [docs](https://github.com/Shopify/quilt/blob/master/packages/koa-shopify-auth/README.md#shopifyauth) but still get the offline access token which does not contain any information about the user.

Comment: How do you know that it is an offline access token ? You will not get the user information. You can request [AccessScope](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/access/accessscope) and it will return associated permissions.

Comment: It is described in [here](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/authenticate-with-oauth#step-3-confirm-installation).

 If online access mode is requested, then the server responds with an access token and additional data

Comment: I haven't used the online access token myself. Just make sure that you are sending access_mode=per-user instead of online or something else.

Comment: I checked the requests with fiddler and it sends access_mode=per-user in query string, but I still do not get associated_user field in the session ((

Comment: I have got it )) the thing is that everything is working fine but `@shopify/koa-shopify-auth` I debugged through it and it receives the data but never puts it in the session